# If $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ continuous and injective, but the inverse is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis

In my course I have that if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and injective, then it is open. In particular, the inverse $f^{-1}:f(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

If $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ this theorem still hold. I found a counter example for $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ when $m>n$. For example $$g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$$
defined by $$g(x,y)=(x,y,0).$$

The function $g$ is continuous, injective but not open since $g(\mathbb R^2)=\mathbb R^2\times \{0\}$ which is closed in $\mathbb R^3$. Her the inverse $$g^{-1}: \mathbb R^2\times \{0\}\to \mathbb R^2$$
defined by $$g^{-1}(x,y,0)=(x,y)$$
is continuous. But could it happen a case where a function $$\psi :\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$$
that is injective, continuous, not open, but the converse is not continuous on $\psi(\mathbb R^2)$ ? I guess it could be but I don't find an example.

Comment: A pedantic point which doesn't really change your argument:  $\mathbb{R}^2\times \{0\}$ is not "not open" because it is closed.  "Open" and "closed" are not opposite to each other, and in more abstract spaces, sets can be "clopen" (both closed and open).  In Euclidean space, the only clopen sets are the whole space and the empty set, but you should keep in mind that "This set isn't open because it is closed" is a fallacious argument.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Thank you for this precision. Indeed... I should say it's not open because it contain no ball of $\mathbb R^3$ (good point :))

Comment: Imagine a path $\gamma:(0,1)\to \Bbb R^2$ where the image looks like a $b$, ie a line and then the path curves back to meet the line in the middle, but the path itself never quite reaches that line since $1$ is not in the domain. This is an injective map but the inverse $\gamma((0,1))\to\Bbb (0,1)$ is not continuous. Modify this example in a suitable manner in order to recover the map you seek.